# Restlet to post Inventory Adjustment

Tags: javascript, netsuite, restlet

I want to ask about Restlet in Netsuite. I try to use it to post to Inventory Adjustment but cant find how to work with it. Here is my code :

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

 define([
  'N/record',
], function (record) {
  function doPost(requestBody) {

  log.debug('Post body', requestBody);

  var inventoryAdjustment = record.create({
      type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT,
      isDynamic: true
  });


 var account = inventoryAdjustment.account;
 var department = inventoryAdjustment.department;
 var adjlocation = inventoryAdjustment.adjlocation;
  inventoryAdjustment.setValue({
  fieldId: 'account',
  value: account
  });
  inventoryAdjustment.setValue({
  fieldId: 'department',
  value: department
  });
  inventoryAdjustment.setValue({
  fieldId: 'adjlocation',
  value: adjlocation
  });

  inventoryAdjustment.selectNewLine({
      sublistId: 'inventory'
  });


  var items = requestBody.line;
  items.forEach(function (inventory) {

      inventoryAdjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'inventory',
          fieldId: 'item',
          value: inventory.item //internal id 
      });

      inventoryAdjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'inventory',
          fieldId: 'quantity',
          value: inventory.quantity
      });
      inventoryAdjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'inventory',
          fieldId: 'rate',
          value: inventory.rate //custom in netsuite
      });

      inventoryAdjustment.commitLine({
          sublistId: 'inventory'
      });
  });

  try {
      var id = inventoryAdjustment.save({
          ignoreMandatoryFields: false
      });
      log.debug('record save with id', id);
      return id;
  } catch (e) {
      return 0;
  }
}

return {
  post: doPost
  };
});
```

When I try to run this code in Postman, there's an error that said :

```
 "TypeError: Cannot read property \'forEach\' of undefined [at Object.doPost (/SuiteScripts/restlet_invadj.js:42:3)]"
```

My json to post look like this :

```
{
"account":113,
"department":102,
"adjlocation":103,
  "inventory":{
    "currentline":
     {
        "item":3569,
        "rate":20000,
        "quantity":5
     }
  
}
```

}

I want to use the Restlet to integrate Netsuite with POS app.
Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You set `var items = requestBody.line;`, however, there is no `line` property in your "JSON to post".  Therefore it's undefined when you try to access the `forEach` method.
2. You may have meant to set `var items = requestBody.currentline;`, however, you still would not be able to call `items.forEach`, as `forEach` is an Array method and would not be available.

Comment: After I search for the sublist field in Inventory Adjustment turn out the sublist required is line1, so I change my code to var items = requestBody.line1. But I still not understand about forEach, how to use it in my code?

Comment: 1) I can't see `line1` in your data - please post the rest of your `requestBody`.  2) `forEach` is an Array method - you need to be working with an array for it to work.  Is `requestBody.line1` an array?

Comment: here is my requestBody : ```{
    "department":1,
    "adjlocation":103,
    "account":113,
    "customer":1075,
      "inventory":{
        "line 1":
            {
            "item":3569,
            "location":103,
            "adjustqtyby":5
            }
    }
}```

Comment: To reference "line 1" in that data you would do `requestBody["line 1"]` because the key contains a space.  The value of this would be an object, not an array so you wouldn't use `forEach` on it.  Note that before any of this you would need to use `JSON.parse(requestBody)` to parse the JSON string into a JavaScript object so your script can work with it.